# Is there are way to upload one file in multiple (input) places on the web using Katalon studio

Tags: java, katalon-studio, webautomation, katalon

I have to upload one file in different places on the web using katalon

I am using:

'Upload test-photo.png to input_browse'

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('input_browse'), 'D:\\test-photo.png'
```

I have to upload the same file on below places

'Upload test-photo.png to Object Repository/TKM/Page_/upload_AB_log'

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object Repository/TKM/Page_/upload_AB_log'), 'D:\\test-photo.png'
```

'Upload test-photo.png to Object Repository/TKM/Page_/Upload_BC_logo'

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object Repository/TKM/Page_/Upload_BC_logo'), 'D:\\test-photo.png'
```

'Upload test-photo.png to Object Repository/TKM/Page_/upload_CD_log'

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object Repository/TKM/Page_/upload_CD_log'), 'D:\\test-photo.png'
```

'Upload test-photo.png to 'Object Repository/TKM/Page_/upload_EF_logo'

```
WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object Repository/TKM/Page_/upload_EF_logo'), 'D:\\test-photo.png'
```

The path/file to upload is the same but needs to upload in different places/input.

I am trying to create the keyword but due to the change of object/input, it's not working for all.

Is there a way to create the keyword that will work for all uploads in katalon studio?

Comment: Please add what have you done this far (keyword code).

Comment: **@Keyword**
 public void uploadfile() {

  WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object'), 'D:\\Users\\Logo.png')
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of writing keywords is code reusability - you can use the same code multiple times but with different parameters.

You could use something like this:

```
uploadfile(testObject, pathToUploadFile) { 
    // add some more code if needed
    WebUI.uploadFile(testObject, pathToUploadFile) 
}
```

so you are passing `testObject` and `pathToUploadFile` as parameters.

For example, to upload `Logo.png` you would use

```
uploadfile(WebUI.uploadFile(findTestObject('Object'), 'D:\\Users\\Logo.png')
```

.